# How do I use custom Dependency Injection in Xamarin.Forms Shell?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to hook into the instantiation of a DataTemplate in a ShellContent in Xamarin.Forms Shell?

I want to use an instance of a type derived from Page that is obtained through custom Dependency Injection. In order to inject ViewModel.

Comment: It seems not supported by Xamarin so far. Here is an [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8359) in Github and is this the same as you want?

Comment: They mention something about `ElementTemplate`. Is there any sample to do so, even if the DI service locator is used explicitly somewhere to resolve view models and bind them to pages?

Comment: I don't think this option will be added, or is even possible (Also not in MAUI.net). Since DataTemplates are created via CreateContent() and down the line with Activator.CreateInstance(). Which does not allow for a DI container.